Go Struct method that uses Pointer Receiver bypassed?
I'm learning fundamentals of Go today but I stumble in this example:
My concern is the ChangeLocation method still changed the Location without the pointing into the memory address.
    package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
    )
    
    type Person struct {
        FirstName, LastName, Location string
    }
    
    func (p *Person) ChangeLocation(newLocation string) { // Limits the access of this method to a pointer
        p.Location = newLocation
    }
    
    func main() {
        p := Person{
            "John",
            "Doe",
            "Route A",
        }
        p.ChangeLocation("Route B")
        fmt.Println(p) // Outputs {John Doe Route B}

    }

Here is the playground

I would say it's working as expected. See pointer receiver and Value vs. Pointer receiver

Thanks for the help!
After following the instructions in pointer receiver I'm enlightened to the difference, but I was confuse because I thought that the method with pointer receiver will be only visible when using &Person.
